# Creating Object models for 3D Object Recognition

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create 3D models of objects for the 3D Object Recognition techniques presented in the [following tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php#correspondence-grouping). I get the feeling that something similar to what I am looking for is done in the first steps of [this tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_recognition.php#vfh-recognition) but is glossed over.

I am wondering if there are any prebuilt packages either through PCL or ROS that cover this or if someone could point me in the best direction for getting started with doing this on my own.

My general thoughts were to use a rotating surface and to have it rotate the object while a kinect would capture information about the object and stitch together the various point clouds that would be generated.

Any input as always is more than welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37151/creating-object-models-for-3d-object-recognition/) by [Medet](https://answers.ros.org/users/2703/medet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You should give a try to roboearth: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth

One of the tutorials (and there are only two) is exactly about recording and creating models. It is straightforward. In addition, roboearth uses pcl extensively in creating models. While you explore this, also think about adding new models to roboearth database (which is also explained in the same tutorial).
Hopefully this helps.

---

Originally posted by [bakhol](https://answers.ros.org/users/2684/bakhol/) with karma: 196 on 2012-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder if you faced the same problem as I. I have been trying to make latest source of roboearth work with fuerte. It compiles, it records, but it cannot save the model. I have noticed that in the past week they have been changing parts of their code (quite frequently). I, in fact, asked them this - http://answers.ros.org/question/37152/is-roboearth-going-through-an-intense-week-of/ - but haven't gotten a response yet.

I believe, soon they will have a version ready, if we can be patient.

To answer your question, I think you could also give the object_recognition stack a try (but I don't have any experience to give an educated point of view). Also check the following out:

http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/links/object_recognition_capture/index.html

---

Originally posted by [bakhol](https://answers.ros.org/users/2684/bakhol/) with karma: 196 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1